# Cannot create linked server - "Data source name not found" error - SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ibm-midrange

I need to setup a linked server between SQL Server and IBM i, using ODBC driver (iSeries Access ODBC driver for Windows). I've been trying using sp_addlinkedserver, and using the assistant ([following this tutorial](https://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2012/09/how-to-setup-odbc-to-ibm-as400.html)), but none of that work.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'MYODBC', 
                                @srvproduct='AS400', 
                                @provider='MSDASQL', 
                                @datasrc='MYODBC';
```

The error I get is "Data source name not found and no default driver specified (Error: 7303)."

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I know where my mistake is. 
I'm sorry I'm a totally newbie with this sort of things.
This ODBC connection to AS/400 is not hosted in the SQL Server (is in my own computer).
Maybe I need to create the ODBC connection inside the server which is containing the sql server connection? In that case, is there another way to connect them?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

1. Verify if the DSN Name (`MYODBC`) exists, especially in `ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)`, if exists re-create it using `ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)`
2. Re-install [ODBC Drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339), and restart the system